# Servidor não lê arquivos png em pasta com codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

O servidor não lê/mostra arquivos PNG mas ele mostra normalmente arquivos JPG. Exemplo:

- host.net/novo/assets/img/arquivo.png (é apresentado no navegador)
- host.net/novo/admin/assets/img/arquivo.png (NÃO é apresentado no navegador)

No caso, estou usando CodeIgniter na admin.

Comment: Você possui uma pasta `admin` com o mesmo caminho que acessa a imagem igual a do link anterior??

Comment: Sim, tenho! Porque?